# Open external page in InAppBrowser android 2.3 doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

i have this little issue, in iOS InAppBrowser works well, but in android no way, i turn on all external page in white list, i put a console.log to see if method is called, but doesn't open here how i handling with that

link : a href="#" onclick="openInAppBrowser('my link);" class="recents">

and the method

```
enter code here

function openInAppBrowser(url){
    console.log('click in app brownser');
    console.log('page: ' + url);
    window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

Any idea? In iOS works fine but in android no way, if any one could help me

Comment: Did you add: `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />` to config.xml? The function gets called because you see your `console.log()` statements, right? Anything in logcat about opening the inAppBrowser? What version of Android, what version of Cordova, and are you testing on a device?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable JavaScript on your webview?

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView)   findViewById(R.id.webview);
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
```